# how do i user pattern matches like search engine

Tags: android, pattern-matching, autocompletetextview

I want to generate Search Suggestions that matches the input in the `AutoCompleteTextView`.

It will check for the matches for the first word I type then all the related words should be populated.

After I type next character then it will match combination of that word and populate the result .

I do not understand how to do pattern matches.

For example: Suppose, there are three country names.
`INDIA, IRAQ, IRAN`.

When I type `I` then I want get All Country names Starting with `I` to be displayed.
When I type `IR` then result should be `IRAN,IRAQ.` ETC.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement will be satisfied in `AutoCompleteTextView` itself.

Threshold is used to set from the length where auto complete show it's suggestion:

For ex:

```
String[] languages={"INDIA", "IRAQ","IRAN"};
AutoCompleteTextView text(AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,languages);
text.setAdapter(adapter);
text.setThreshold(1);
```

Comment: in that appears all the word content "I". Suppose there is AMERICA. then it  will also appear all 4 Countries

Comment: you want to show AMERICA in your application or you don't want to show it!

Comment: no i don't want and at once i search any word and erase it it will not show any word in suggation

Comment: Then this code will satisfy your requirement. If you erase it won't show you suggestion. Just now I check it again.